# how to find the limit $ \lim_{x\to -\infty} xe^x = 0 $ using only simple algebraic manipulation

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I found the following limit in an exercise book:
$$ \lim_{x\to -\infty} xe^x = 0 $$
this limit is supposed to be solvable without knowledge of L'hospital nor more advanced techniques such as Taylor or others.
So the question is, how can I find that this limit is $ 0 $ using only simple algebraic manipulation or the common limit list?

Comment: It depends on what you know about the exponential function. For a starter, what is your *definition* of $e^x$?

Comment: 1) What textbook are you using and 2) what makes you think "this limit is supposed to be solvable without knownledge of hopital nor more advanced tecnics such as taylor or others"? Please provide further context. What are "advanced tecnics"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a substitution: set $t=-x\;(t\to+\infty)$. You then have to find the limit of $\;-\dfrac t{\mathrm e^ t}$ when $t\to+\infty$. It's a high school result that this limit is $0$.

However, here is the standard proof in high school:

Taking the log, it amounts to proving that
$\lim_{t\to +\infty}(\ln t-t)=-\infty$.

For this, you need a lemma:

> For all $t\ge 1$, one has $\;\ln t < 2\sqrt t$.

This is an easy consequence of the inequality on derivatives
$$\frac 1t <\frac 1{\sqrt {t\mkern2mu}}$$
and the fact that $\ln 1 < 2\sqrt 1$.

Using this lemma, we have, for all $t>1$:
$$\ln t-t < 2\sqrt t-t\to -\infty\enspace\text{when}\enspace t\to +\infty.$$

Comment: so the point is in the substitution, the limit  $\;-\dfrac t{\mathrm e^ t}$ is cleary $0$ thanks

Comment: i believe you can find that $\;-\dfrac t{\mathrm e^ t}$ is 0 when $t\to+\infty$ also by noting that e^t increase more quicky than t, <br> that is probably what was expected to know for this execise

Comment: ‘noting that $\mathrm e^t$ increases more quickly than $t$’ is vague and in no way a mathematical assertion. $t$ also increases more quickly, yet the ratio  is constant, equal to $2$. So either  you take this result for granted (for instance, because it's been proved in high school) or you prove it in a mathematical way.

Comment: is the ratio costant and equal to 2? try to plot the function $x/e^x$, it will never be greater than 1

Comment: @math_mx: Sorry, there was a mistyping in my previous comment: I meant to say,  as an example, that $\color{red}{2}t$ increases more quickly than $t$, yes the ratio is constant, equal to $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to -\infty} xe^x= \lim_{x\to \infty}(-x)\frac{1}{e^x}$, hence we investigate

$\lim_{x\to \infty}x \frac{1}{e^x}$.

For $x>0$ we have $e^x \ge \frac{x^2}{2}$ (power series expansion). Thus

$ 0 \le \frac{x}{e^x} \le \frac{2}{x}$. This gives: $\lim_{x\to \infty}x \frac{1}{e^x}=0$.

Therefore $\lim_{x\to -\infty} xe^x=0$.

Comment: Why the downvote ? What is not useful in my answer ?

Comment: the question specifically asks for a solution not using power series

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=-y\to +\infty$

$$xe^x=-\frac{y}{e^y}\to 0$$

by squeeze theorem. Indeed since by exponential series $e^y>\frac{y^2}2$

$$0<\frac{y}{e^y}<\frac{2y}{y^2}=\frac2y\to 0$$

Comment: simple and easy thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, Bye!

Comment: I think  $e^y>y^2/2$ would be more obvious from the exponential series. But your inequality is also fine. +1

Comment: you are right at all!